# Dynamic Create View with Multiple Nested IEnumerable Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ok, I have 3 models.  WorkoutViewModel has a one to many relationship with WorkoutExerciseViewModel.  WorkoutExerciseViewModel has a one to many relationship with ExerciseSetViewModel.  I need a dynamic “Create View”, that will allow me dynamically add Exercises to Workouts, and Sets to Exercises.  I then want to save a Workout including all exercise and set records back to the database.  I just need to validate that there is at least 1 exercise for the workout created and at least 1 set for the exercise created.  Ultimately I just need to push a Workout View Model back to the controller with all of the populated nested IEnumberable objects present.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public class WorkoutViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtal IEnumerable<WorkoutExerciseViewModel> WorkoutExercises { get; set;}
}

public class WorkoutExerciseViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    public virtual ExerciseViewModel Exercise { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ExerciseSetViewModel> ExerciseSets { get; set; }

    public string ExerciseFullname 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Exercise.Equipment.Name + " " + Exercise.Name;
        }
    }
}

public class ExerciseSetViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutExerciseId { get; set; }
    public int Set { get; set; }
    public int Reps { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string WeightValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really more to this than can reasonably be discussed in a StackOverflow answer, but I'll give you enough to start with.

As far as adding new exercises and sets within those exercises go, that's just JavaScript. You'll need to have some button that the user can click to add a new one, and tie the click event on that button to a handler that will add the appropriate HTML (form fields and such) to the page. There's many different ways to go about doing that, some more difficult than others. Most likely you want to look into some JavaScript templating library or a more full stack JS library like Knockout to make things easier. The only other thing to keep in mind is the conventions the modelbinder uses to wire everything from the post body to an instance of your model. For collections, it expects fields to have name attributes in the form of `CollectionPropertyName[N].PropertyBeingEdited`, where `N` is the position within the collection. So, the name attribute for `ExerciseFullName` for the first exercise would be `WorkoutExercises[0].ExerciseFullName`.

Your post action would simply take your same main view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(WorkoutViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

As long as you follow the property naming conventions for all the fields in your form, the modelbinder will happily wire everything from the post body onto your `WorkoutViewModel` instance.